# How to create multiple variants of a page in page manager

Tags: 8, panels

I'm attempting to create multiple pages that use panels within a page in page manager.

For example I'm trying to create the path

```
127.0.0.1/brands
```

And have multiple pages that follow that same path like the following

```
127.0.0.1/brands/brand1
127.0.0.1/brands/brand2
127.0.0.1/brands/brand3
```

I created multiple variants for each brand in the brands page manager. I had a feeling that I could create the various subpages by using the 'Request Path' selection condition. But I've attempted the following

```
/brands/brand1
/brand1
```

and all of these lead to a 'page requested not found' when visiting 127.0.0.1/brands/brand1

Is there a way to create a sub page of a page using page manager, without creating a whole new page?

Comment: have you tried smth like brands/% ?

Comment: @milkovsky I think OP is trying to get this work on D8, and the wildcards in D8 have changed. Something like `brands/{brand}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a page with the url /brands and add your variants. Use the "String: URL Path" selection rule to manage each one.

How to:

Under selection rules for the main (panel) page add the "String: URL Path" rule with a single line "/brands"

Do the same with the variants but:
Under the first variant use /brands/brand1 
Under the second variant use /brands/brand2
...
...

[image]

Comment: That's how I would do it on Drupal 7 but I don't see how to apply the same rules on drupal 8.